# while updating(editing) its not taking the old audio file name

Tags: java, android, media-player

having one text and audio(recording) and saving the name and path in db.while clicking the name that audio has to play its playing also.But while editing if i supposed to change the name alone,it will not take the old file name of the respective one,its make that one as null.

How to take the old audio file name if people will not update the audio(recording)

audioactivity.java

```
private void saveState() {
      String audioname = et1.getText().toString();

      String audiofilename = gfilename;
      String audiocount = et2.getText().toString();

        if(audiocount.equals("")){
            audiocount ="1"; 
        }


      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        String audiodate = sdf.format(new Date());


      if (mRowId == null || mRowId.longValue() == 0)
      {

        long id = mDbHelper.createProject4(audioname, audiofilename, audiocount, audiodate);
          if (id > 0) {
              mRowId = id;
          }
      } else {
          audiofilename=gfilename;
          mDbHelper.updateProject4(mRowId, audioname, audiofilename, audiocount,audiodate);
      }


  }


  public View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() 
  {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.btnStart:{
                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                    enableButtons(true);
                    startRecording();

                    break;
                }
                case R.id.btnstop:{
                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                    enableButtons(false);
                    stopRecording();

                    break;

                }

            }
        }

    };

    public MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            AppLog.logString("Error: " + what + ", " + extra);
        }
    };

    public MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            AppLog.logString("Warning: " + what + ", " + extra);
        }
    };


    public void setButtonHandlers() {
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
      ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);

    }

    public void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
        ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
    }

    public void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
        enableButton(R.id.btnStart,!isRecording);           
        enableButton(R.id.btnstop,isRecording);
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void startRecording(){
        //displayFormatDialog();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        String formats[] = {"MPEG 4", "3GPP", "AMR"};

        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.choose_format_title))
               .setSingleChoiceItems(formats, currentFormat, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    currentFormat = which;


                    dialog.dismiss();





        recorder = new MediaRecorder();         
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
        recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());          
        //recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
        //recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                   }
               })
               .show();
    }



private void stopRecording(){
    if(null != recorder)
    {
        //mDbHelper.updateProject4FileName(mRowId, gfilename); 
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();             
        recorder = null;
        }
    else
    {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();     
    }
}


    public String getFilename(){

        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        gfilename = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
        return (gfilename);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCompletion (MediaPlayer arg0) 
    {               
    }

  public void  playSong(String gfilename){
      // Play song
         try
         {
          mp.reset();
          mp.setDataSource(gfilename);
          mp.prepare();
          mp.start();

          // Changing Button Image to pause image
          btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);


      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

I checked in debugging also,if we didnt update the recording its taking that place as null only.

Here i attached my db updated code also

```
public boolean updateProject4(long _id, String audioname, String audiofilename,String audiocount,String audiodate) {
                            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                            args.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_AUDIONAME, audioname );
                            args.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_AUDIOFILENAME, audiofilename );
                            args.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_AUDIOCOUNT, audiocount );
                            args.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_AUDIODATE, audiodate );
                            return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE_AUDIOPRAYER, args, CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID4 + "=" + _id,  null) > 0;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got the way for my question.

Want to fetchfile from db if my filename becomes null while updating

```
private void saveState() {
      String audioname = et1.getText().toString();

      String audiofilename = gfilename;
      String audiocount = et2.getText().toString();

        if(audiocount.equals("")){
            audiocount ="1"; 
        }






      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        String audiodate = sdf.format(new Date());

      //String reqname= spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
      //Log.i(" save state mathod "," values are "+title+Desc+Body+reqname); 

      if (mRowId == null || mRowId.longValue() == 0)
      {

        long id = mDbHelper.createProject4(audioname, audiofilename, audiocount, audiodate);
          if (id > 0) {
              mRowId = id;
          }
      } else {


          if(audiofilename.equals("")){
              Cursor filename = mDbHelper.fetchProject4FileName(mRowId, audiofilename);
               startManagingCursor(filename);
               gfilename =filename.getString(filename.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_AUDIOFILENAME));
            //mDbHelper.fetchProject4FileName(mRowId, audiofilename);
            audiofilename = gfilename;
            mDbHelper.updateProject4(mRowId, audioname, audiofilename, audiocount,audiodate);
        }
          else
          {
              audiofilename =  gfilename;
              mDbHelper.updateProject4(mRowId, audioname, audiofilename, audiocount,audiodate);
          }




      }
```

we have to fetch the filename from db and check whether our audiofilename is null means,we have to set the older filename

Comment: go ahead accept your answer. it will help others who visit the post

Comment: i can't accept your answer. but you can mark you answer as accepted by clicking the tick once